# Class Data Sharing при контейнеризации

Tags: java, classloader

Проблема:
На сервере запускается некоторое число микросервисов (Spring Boot 2, Java 17)
По умолчанию в JDK 12+ включена опция [Class Data Sharing](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/vm/class-data-sharing.html), что даёт существенный выигрыш по используемой памяти сервера (~50 МБайт на микросервис).

Если переходить на систему контейнеризации, то данным преимуществом JDK воспользоваться не удастся?

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Я видел что IBM в своей виртуальной машине это позволяют делать. Они создают `VOLUME` в докере и указывают ту папку в качестве кеша для `sharedClasses` для процессов джавы в разных контейнерах. Но одноименных настроек в православных реализациях JVM я не видел(и не особо искал)...возможно что-то подобное есть

Comment: если сами решение найдете - оставьте ответ, пожалуйста и пинганите если не сложно)) (самому интересно)